# Remove gnome from Xubuntu

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, xfce, 15.10

I tried out Gnome-shell on Xubuntu 15.10 by installing the meta-package "gnome". I didn't like it much, so I want to remove it again.

I tried `apt-get purge gnome && apt-get autoremove`, but unfortunately I got an error on boot, so I decided to reinstall gnome. Everything works fine, but I'd like to get rid of gnome again.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

`Switch on` your computer.

Press and hold the `Shift key`, which will bring up the Grub menu.

Select the line which starts with `Advanced options`.

Select the line ending with `(recovery mode)`

Press `Return` and your machine will begin the boot process.

Your computer should display a menu with a number of options.

One of the options will be `Enable networking`. Press Return with this option highlighted.

Other of the options will be `Drop to root shell prompt`. Press Return with this option highlighted.

In the terminal enter the commands:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(gnome),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(xubuntu-desktop))))'
apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop
apt-get dist-upgrade
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```